# How do you specify Exponential distribution in glm() in R?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, exponential-distribution

In glm() function, it seems that you can specify Normal, Gamma, Inverse Gaussian, Poisson, Binomial, and quasi families. See here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html. But how do you specify an Exponential distribution?

Comment: The exponential distribution is a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $1$.

Comment: Answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240455/fitting-exponential-regression-model-by-mle ... both Ben's answer and mine contain the essential information (his was just after mine but with more details)

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to get plots and fitted values after summary(glm.fit, dispersion = 1), where glm.fit is the fitted glm? I used to do plot(glm.fit) and fitted.values(glm.fit)...